# How to I retrieve the ID from the Posts page?

Tags: posts, custom-field, metabox, post-meta, id

I am creating some custom meta boxes in my theme to allow user to insert their own custom meta description and keywords overrides (no I will not use a plugin for it). I am having an issue with the posts page as when I'm trying to retrieve the ID for it by using:

```
$custom_seo_desc = \get_post_meta( $this->post->ID, 'custom_page_desc' );
```

I keep returning the ID of the first post that appears on the posts page, not the actual ID of the parent page itself. Therefore I cannot seem to set any custom meta data description.

I've done some google searches and I'm stumped for an answer, all I get is articles on how to locate page and posts ID, nothing for a designated posts page.

Does anyone out there have a solution?

Comment: `global $wp_query; $post_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();` try this to find id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `get_queried_object_id()` to retrieve the page ID.

```
$custom_seo_desc = \get_post_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'custom_page_desc' );
```

You can verify the page for posts ID by looking at the option `page_for_posts`.

```
$posts_page_id = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
```